# How can I use JHipster's filter Pipe?

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-pipe

I'm implementing a web application with *JHipster 6.0.1* and *Angular*.

I must hide `USER ROLE` authority in each row of user management home. With that end I decided to implement a filter pipe and use it here.

```
 <div *ngFor="let authority of user.authorities">
   <span class="badge badge-info">{{ authority }}</span>
 </div>
```

First I decided to investigate if *JHipster* already provides a filter pipe. I've found on [Github](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/pipe/filter.pipe.ts) that *JHipster* has a filter `Pipe` implemented. Although I didn't find how to use it in JHipster's documentation.

My question is:

How can I use the *JHipster* filter `Pipe` in order to hide `USER ROLE` authority in each row of user management home ?

Comment: it looks like you can use it like `| filter('ROLE_USER' !== authority)`, give it a try

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro I'll try it

Comment: if it works, let me know to post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Alejandro that won't work because authority is within the scope of the pipe. The pipe only applies to user.authorities